# How to Internationalization in java Annotations

Tags: java, localization, annotations, internationalization

I want to internationalize the annotation in java, **but the project is not based on spring.**

(Sorry I'm a freshman in Java. The project is in NiFi and I don't know what it using. The project was built by Maven, Generating a NAR package that defines the processor is the purpose of the project build)(NAR package is a concept in NiFi. Similar to jar package, NAR package consists of multiple jar packages and configuration files.)

Is there any way to use the replacement symbol $ in non spring project? To refer to the translated text in Messages.properties like
`@CapabilityDescription(value = "${text}").`

and set `text="description"`in Messages.properties

I try ResourceBundle.getString in annotation but failed(Attribute value must be constant)
`@CapabilityDescription(MyResourceBundle.mybundle.getString("text"))`

this is the definition code of CapabilityDescription

```
 * Annotation that may be placed on a {@link org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor Processor},
 * {@link org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService ControllerService}, or
 * {@link org.apache.nifi.reporting.ReportingTask ReportingTask} allowing for a
 * description to be provided. This description can be provided to a user in
 * logs, UI, etc.
 *
 */
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface CapabilityDescription {

    String value();
}
```

Or any idea that can realize the internationalization in annotation. Thank you for your idea.

Thanks for @Holger I find the code that reading the annotation. (DtoFactory.java In another project)

```
/**
 * Gets the capability description from the specified class.
 */
private String getCapabilityDescription(final Class<?> cls) {
    final CapabilityDescription capabilityDesc = cls.getAnnotation(CapabilityDescription.class);
    return capabilityDesc == null ? null : capabilityDesc.value();
}
```

Comment: “the project is not based on spring”. That’s a valuable information, but even better would be telling what you are using instead. In the end, there must be code reading the annotation and presenting the user a message based on that annotation. *This code* is responsible for doing the internationalization.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your help. I update the question and add the code reading the annotation. I will try to add internationalization code in 'getCapabilityDescription' function next Monday and update this problem. Thank you for your help again, This problem really bothers me. I'm so stupid that I can't find any solution to the internationalization of non spring project annotations on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Holger's help. I modified the code dealing with "CapabilityDescription" and successfully implemented the requirements.

```
/**
 * Gets the capability description from the specified class.
 */
private String getCapabilityDescription(final Class<?> cls) {
    try {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale("zh");
        ResourceBundle myLanguageBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages", myLocale);
        return myLanguageBundle.getString("CapabilityDescription_"+cls.getSimpleName());
    }catch (Exception e){
        final CapabilityDescription capabilityDesc = cls.getAnnotation(CapabilityDescription.class);
        return capabilityDesc == null ? null : capabilityDesc.value();
    }

}
```